# How to fix leaking MySQL conns with Go?

Tags: mysql, go

I have data on my local computer in 2 MySQL databases (dbConnOuter and dbConnInner) that I want to process and collate into a 3rd database (dbConnTarget).

The code runs for about 17000 cycles, then stops with these error messages:

```
[mysql] 2018/08/06 18:20:57 packets.go:72: unexpected EOF
[mysql] 2018/08/06 18:20:57 packets.go:405: busy buffer
```

As far as I can tell I'm properly closing the connections where I'm reading from and I'm using `Exec` for writing, that I believe handles its own resources. I've also tried prepared statements, but it didn't help, the result was the same.

Below is the relevant part of my code, and it does similar database operations prior to this without any issues.

As this is one of my first experiments with Go, I can't yet see where I might be wasting my resources.

```
import (
    "database/sql"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

var dbConnOuter *sql.DB
var dbConnInner *sql.DB
var dbConnTarget *sql.DB

func main() {
    dbConnOuter = connectToDb(dbUserDataOne)
    dbConnInner = connectToDb(dbUserDataTwo)
    dbConnTarget = connectToDb(dbUserDataThree)
    // execute various db processing functions
    doStuff()
}

func connectToDb(dbUser dbUser) *sql.DB {
    dbConn, err := sql.Open("mysql", fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/%v", dbUser.username, dbUser.password, dbUser.dbname))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    dbConn.SetMaxOpenConns(500)
    return dbConn
}

// omitted similar db processing functions that work just fine

func doStuff() {
    outerRes, err := dbConnOuter.Query("SELECT some outer data")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer outerRes.Close()

    for outerRes.Next() {
        outerRes.Scan(&data1)
        innerRes, err := dbConnInner.Query("SELECT some inner data using", data1)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        innerRes.Scan(&data2, &data3)
        innerRes.Close()

        dbConnTarget.Exec("REPLACE INTO whatever", data1, data2, data3)
    }
}
```

Comment: For some general guidance on Go MySQL connection handling: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/461

Comment: Explicitly giving all the connections max 500 open connections seems strange when, based on the given code, you need only 1 open connection per database.

Comment: Have you actually confirmed via netstat that the application has an escalating number of connections to the database open, or is that a guess based on the crash error?

Comment: @Adrian, it was just a guess, and looks like the number of connections is not escalating. Previously I had such problems and that 500 for the open connections seemed to help (As Someone Has Suggested On The Internet). This is something new though. Maybe I should check an alternative package for connecting to MySQL.

Comment: Googling the error turned up [this issue]() which suggests `db.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Second * 10)` might help, as well as tweaking mysqld's own timeouts in my.cnf. It could be the connections are idling out during long-running queries.

Comment: I've tried that, and also SetConnMaxLifetime(0) -- forever --, but it made no difference. Switching from `database/sql` to `github.com/siddontang/go-mysql/client` did the trick with the same queries, but this API somehow feels less elegant. Anyway, at least my data has been converted now, and I still need to learn a lot about Go.